# Unsolved reference: Databaserefernce && Expecting member - firebase livedatabase && Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

`I have an error on:

[image]

``

```
package com.example.movietime

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.movietime.databinding.ActivityRegisterBinding
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // also here with all sentence
    // binding
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityRegisterBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        // move  to login after click
        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActiivty::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

```
building grade(:app)
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.movietime'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.movietime"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

```
build grade(project)
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

``

`I'm kind of lost already,
tried this
[Unresolved reference:database for Firebase Realtime database in my Kotlin program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72259052/unresolved-referencedatabase-for-firebase-realtime-database-in-my-kotlin-progra?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

but it didnt help either.

any suggestion will be welcome!

[Unresolved reference:database for Firebase Realtime database in my Kotlin program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72259052/unresolved-referencedatabase-for-firebase-realtime-database-in-my-kotlin-progra?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

Reconnection the firebase to project and import from begging.`

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72259052/unresolved-referencedatabase-for-firebase-realtime-database-in-my-kotlin-progra) but in your case, the problem isn't related to the import but to the name of the class. So you're getting the following error:

> Unsolved reference: Databaserefernce

Because there is no class that is called `Databaserefernce` but [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference). See the capital `R`? To solve this, please change the type of the variable to `DatabaseReference`, add the corresponding import and the error will go away.

Besides that, the way you're initializing the variable is not correct. That's how you do it in Java. In Kotlin you should do it like this:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
```

Comment: Hey Adir. Can I help you with other information? Did my answer help you?